# Can't send float values from one Arduino to another:

Tags: arrays, arduino, floating

I'm doing a project in which I want to send three float values from one Arduino to another and store these float values in an array in the receiving Arduino. While printing the received float values I can see only first two digits in the serial monitor.

I'm a beginner and don't know how to get the whole float values. Please help me with the program. Here I've posted the transmitter and receiver code.
Transmitter’s Code:

```
float transmit[3]={72.453444,83.345678,60}; //Values to be sent

 void setup()
{
Serial.begin(115200);
int i;
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
Serial.write(transmit[i]);
}
}
void loop()
{
}

 Receiver’s Code:
 float received[3];     //create an float array
int i;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
 }
void loop()
{
 while(Serial.available()>0)
 {
  for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
  {
    received[i]=(Serial.read());
   delay(10);
    }
    Serial.println(received[0]);  
    Serial.println(received[1]);  
    Serial.println(received[2]);   
 }
}
```

> ```
> Values received on Serial Monitor:
> 72
> 83
> 60
> ```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing the first two digits; you are seeing the integer part of it. This is because Serial.Write accepts integer values, so your floats are converted to int (i.e. truncated) and then sent.

If you want to pass them "as they are", you can first cast the values' array to a byte array, then send it "raw"; when receiving you just have to receive all the bytes and.. you are done. Here is the code:

Sender's code:

```
float transmit[3]={72.453444,83.345678,60}; //Values to be sent

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.write((uint8_t*)transmit, 3 * sizeof(float));
}
void loop()
{
}
```

Receiver’s Code:

```
float received[3];     //create an float array
int i;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
}
void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available() >= 3 * sizeof(float));
    {
        uint8_t *recv_bytes = (uint8_t*)transmit;
        for(i=0; i < 3 * sizeof(float); i++)
        {
            recv_bytes[i] = Serial.read();
        }
        Serial.println(received[0]);  
        Serial.println(received[1]);  
        Serial.println(received[2]);   
    }
}
```

Note 1: I haven't tested this, so there could be errors.. Try and, if it doesn't work, we'll look at it again

Note 2: this should work, but you will have a lot of problems in "real life" because you don't have a way to detect the start and stop points in the transmission-. For a robust communication, consider adding something like byte escaping or reserving a bit bor handshaking

Note 3: this will only work on systems with the same size of float and same endianness (e.g. between two arduinos). When interfacing with other systems (e.g. a PC or a mobile or who knows) you will NEED to explicitely convert a number, since endianness or float length mismatch makes the communication impossible using the automatic cast I used

Comment: Thanks for your work..but still getting error in both transmitting and receiving program.. In transmitting program I got the error as "no matching function for call to 'Hardware serial::write(float[3],unsigned int)'".

Comment: In receiver's program I got the error as "cannot convert 'float to 'uint8_t*'in initialization".

Comment: @Krish Ok, maybe it doesn't like implicit cast. Try explicitely casting the pointers to `uint8_t*` (see the answer since I corrected the code; you have to change two lines - one in the sender and one in the receiver)

Comment: This code might help me but in the output I get many zeros in between the values.    output: 77.12    88.23    60.00    0.00    0.00   0.00    0.00   How to print the values alone and I'm getting only two digits after decimal point.